# Integration without curve formula

Tags: integration, area

*My mathematic English is poor, if the question have already been asked with some other therms, I apology*

I need to process the area of a curve (between two points) which is not drawn from a formula but from measured values. I didn't find any useful tips in Google.

Here's an example:

[image]

I need to calculate the area of the green part. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The area of a curve is not drawn from a formula, but from measured values*.

The integral is a Riemann sum, is it not ? And you already know the value of each $f(x_k)$ for each $x_k$ , correct ? So all you have to do is compute the finite series $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}f\big(x_k\big)\cdot\big(x_{k+1}-x_k\big)$.

Comment: I tried your solution which gave me 82807 and the `average*(Xmax-Xmin)` and found 82805.96. Did I made a wrong implementation?

Comment: Yup, I made a wrong implementation. Thanks :)

Comment: Other attempts can be made with the trapezoidal rule, Simpson's rule, and other "numerical integration" methods.